# How to create and print nsum or nprod style expression?

Tags: sympy

Is it possible to print `nsum` or `nprod` style express?

e.g.

```
n = Symbol('n')
nsum(lambda n: 1/fac(n), [0, inf]) #this calculates e
```

is there any way to create and print an expression of like [definition of e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

[image: e]

or [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean)

[image: geometric average]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nsum` is not a SymPy function, it's an mpmath function (mpmath was a submodule of SymPy once upon a time; if you are still using ancient SymPy version, an upgrade is recommended).

In SymPy, summation is implemented by [Sum](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#sympy.concrete.summations.Sum), which is unevaluated summation until `.doit()` method is called. Example:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> init_printing()
>>> Sum(1/factorial(n), (n, 0, oo))
  ∞     
 ____   
 ╲      
  ╲   1 
   ╲  ──
   ╱  n!
  ╱     
 ╱      
 ‾‾‾‾   
n = 0 
>>> Sum(1/factorial(n), (n, 0, oo)).doit()
ℯ
```

Here `init_printing()` initiates the printing of "pretty" expressions; how pretty they are depends on your environment (I'm using a text terminal in this example). [More on printing in SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html).

Similarly, there is [Product](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#sympy.concrete.products.Product) for products.

But the formulas you give an example make me think you are looking for something presentation-oriented, which calls for opening LaTeX editor and typing those formulas.